# .htaccess URL rewrite fails on Safari / iPad / iOS

Tags: php, ios, apache, .htaccess, safari

So I have an .htaccess URL rewrite rule that works perfectly fine on Firefox, Chrome, etc. on various operating systems.  However, on iPad with Safari, it fails with "too many redirects".

An example of the code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?c=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas why it only fails on that specific browser and platform?  Have already checked the caching in Safari, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried putting the https rules first?

Comment: Are there too many redirects if you start with https on the iPad?

Comment: If I enter the address as https://example.com it does give me the same response.  I haven't tried moving the HTTPS rule first but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Nope, moving that HTTPS rule completely messes it up for all browsers on all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not with the HTACCESS file but more a redirection on the server itself; which possibly conflicted with the HTACCESS file.

However, as to why it ONLY affected iPad/iPhone with Safari is beyond me.